# $.when does not work with $.scrollTo plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `scrollTo` plugin, I would like to scroll take position what I want, after that work alert function. My prototype code like that. It does not work, what is my mistake?

```
 $.when(function () {
        $.scrollTo('#documentsFieldset', 1000);
    }).done(function () {
        alert('completed');
    });
```

Comment: some more whitespace (namely newlines) could help readability.

Comment: Best guess is that the plugin doesn't support promises.

Comment: `$.when` isn't a magic method to know when something happens, it's a sort of callback for deferreds and promises.

Comment: scrollTo has an option called `onAfter` that's called upon completing scrolling, use it. If you want to use deferreds/promises you have to call them manually. Usage 
`$.scrollTo('#documentsFieldset',1000, { onAfter: function() { alert('lol') })`

Comment: @adeneo but, when you pass it a promise, then it returns a promise wrapping that promise. That is sort of nice to have.

Comment: @ArtekWiśnia you should convert that to an answer.

Comment: @ArtekWiśnia thank you for answer. Your answer is exactly answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

`$.when` only accepts [deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) and [promises](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/). Unfortunately, `$.scrollTo` returns nothing, `undefined`, so that's not going to work.

When you *do* try passing `$.scrollTo`'s result to `$.when`, it will forgive you and treat it as "no promises given", returning an immediate promise. Thus, your `done` callback is immediately invoked and does not wait for the scrolling to complete.

One solution would be to pass a callback as third argument, or set it as the `onAfter` property of the third argument:

```
$.scrollTo('#documentsFieldset', 1000, function() {
    alert('completed');
});
// or alternatively, e.g. if you need to pass more settings
$.scrollTo('#documentsFieldset', 1000, {
    onAfter: function() {
        alert('completed');
    }
});
```

Another solution would be to make a wrapper around `$.scrollTo` which returns a promise so you can happily use it in your `$.when` calls to combine it with other asynchronous stuff. I went ahead to try this out, [go check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MattiasBuelens/y349P/).

Answer (score 0):

You have wrapped the call to scrollTo in a anonymous function which does not return a deferred object. 
<strike>If you only want to react when scrollTo is done the following would be sufficient:</strike>

```
$.when(
       $.scrollTo("#selector", 1000)
).done(function(){
     console.log("scroll finished");
});
```

edit:
I was mistaken in thinking $.scrollTo would return a deferred object - it does not!
But the API offers the callback onAfter.
So the solution would look like this:

```
$.scrollTo("#selector", 1000, {
   onAfter: function() {
      console.log("done!");
   }
});
```

Comment: Did you try this? In the [current version of the plugin](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/blob/f3302f9d759c44e8232f0565aacbd2b90e1d5dc9/jquery.scrollTo.js), `$.scrollTo` (not `$.fn.scrollTo`) returns *nothing at all*, i.e. `undefined`. `$.when` is forgiving though and treats no promises as an immediate promise, triggering your `done` callback immediately. You'll need to use the `onAfter` callback (or make some kind of wrapper which binds to `onAfter` to resolves a promise).

Comment: you are absolutely right!
sorry for that! I just saw the anonymous function not returning anything in the original post.

Comment: True, but that was just *half* of the problem. :-P